# Protect website against attacks with iframe for user generated javascript?

Tags: xss, javascript, webserver, iframe

I'm creating a small playground for people to write and test out their JavaScript on my website. I know websites like jsfiddle already exist but it's just for fun and for the sake of trying something new.

Now I know people can hack my site pretty badly with XSS and other things so I came up with a few ways to prevent havoc:

1. As usual, people write their JavaScript and HTML in a form. It's pure text. Nothing functional.
2. When wanting to test out the code the data is sent from www.A.com to www.B.com
3. On that domain, the data is written to an iframe with the sandbox feature on without the "allow-top-navigation" option.
4. The iframe is then sent back to www.A.com
5. www.A.com receives iframe and appends it as a child into the DOM.
6. The user sees the iframe and can interact with it.

Is this secure enough? or am I missing something crucial?

Comment: Are users able to sign in or otherwise do anything meaningfully sensitive on www.A.com? If not, then honestly you don't really need a sandbox; XSS doesn't gain anybody any meaningful increase in privileges. Might still be a good idea to practice the sandboxing, but remember: not all sites actually care about XSS, etc. because it's an elevation of privilege attack, and on many sites, no user has any privileges that any other user doesn't.

Comment: @CBHacking yes they can register, login and save their code. The code is stored in a database. Should I consider it in this case?